FFmpeg: To trim a video using 'trim' and specify time using HH:MM:SS format
FFmpeg 7.0.1. I want to understand whether it is possible to trim a video using trim and to specify start and end time using the HH:MM:SS format instead of just seconds.
That is, the following command trims a video from 5s to 10s:
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf trim=5:10,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS output.mp4

But if I try to specify start and end time using HH:MM:SS format, FFmpeg returns an error:
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf trim='00:00:05':'00:00:15',setpts=PTS-STARTPTS output.mp4

ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -vf trim=00\:00\:05:00\:00\:15,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS output.mp4


Output file is empty, nothing was encoded(check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)

Is it possible to fix it? (A guy on Super User suggested trim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:15' or trim=00\\:00\\:05:00\\:00\\:15, but I receive the same error message.)
Side questions

To keep the first 5 seconds and drop everything else, I can use ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf trim=end=5 output.mp4. But how to keep only the last 5 seconds?

To drop frist 5 seconds, I can use ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf trim=start=5,setpts=PTS-STARTPTS output.mp4. But how to drop the last 5 seconds?



Cut using a duration
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:05:20 -t 00:10:00 -c:v copy -c:a copy output1.mp4
Cut using a specific time
$ ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -ss 00:05:10 -to 00:15:30 -c:v copy -c:a copy output2.mp4
source

Thanks, but what if I prefer to use '-trim'? A guy on Super User who calls himslef "FFmpeg maintainer" suggested to use trim='00\:00\:05':'00\:00\:15', but I receive the same error message.

@jsx97 This is correct.  You should use -ss and -to.  Although, you can shorten the -c:v and -c:a to a single -c copy.

@JayCravens Hello, Jay. What exactly you mean by "This is correct"? Do you mean the solution from that guy on Super User is correct? But then why it doesn't work for me? Or you mean that trim won't work with the HH:MM:SS format, and so to use the HH:MM:SS format I should use the -ss .. -to approach?

@jsx97  Precisely.  A filter is not optimal for cutting out sections.  Using -ss & -to will also eliminate any need to adjust the PTS's.

@JayCravens But isn't trim is created for a very purpose to trim videos? In other words, what are the reasons to think it is a second-class thing for trimming videos?

@jsx97 The fact that so few people ever succeed using it.  I've never failed with -ss / -to.  Proof is in the pudding.
